# Angular 5 - Multiple pipe filters not working in an array of objects

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have a angular component which has got 3 filters (category, rating & price) and when selecting those filters I have to show only the appropriate data so I have created a Pipe and passed in all three selected values. Actually my category filter works completely fine but the other two filters (rating & price) are not working properly.

### Json data:

```
"allBusiness": [    
        {
            "category": "XYZ",
            "description": "something something",
            "business": [
             {
                "type": "Store",
                "rating": 4,
                "price" : "$"
             },
             {
                "type": "Store",
                "rating": 3,
                "price" : "$"
             },
             {
                "type": "Store",
                "rating": 5,
                "price" : "$$"
             }           
             ]

        },
        {
            "category": "ABC",
            "description": "Testing",
            "business": [
             {
                "type": "Online",
                "rating": 3,
                "price" : "$"
             },
             {
                "type": "Store",
                "rating": 2,
                "price" : "$"
             },
             {
                "type": "Store",
                "rating": 1,
                "price" : "$$"
             }           
             ]

        }
]
```

### FilterPipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(allBusiness: any[], selectedCategory: string, selectedRating: number, selectedPrice: string): any {
    if (allBusiness && allBusiness.length){
        return allBusiness.filter(item =>{
            if (category && item.category.indexOf(selectedCategory) === -1){
                return false;
            }
            if (rate && item.business.filter(rt => rt.rating != selectedRating)){ //tried filter, findIndex, some but nothing works
                return false;
            }
            if (price && item.business.find(pr => pr.price != selectedPrice)){ //same here nothing is working
                return false;
            }
            return true;
       })
    }
    else{
        return items;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 2 filters: for outer list and inner list, let me split it to `allBusinessFilterBy: {category?: string}` and `businessFilterBy: {rating?: number; price?: string;}`.

```
interface BusinessFilterBy {
  rating?: number;
  price?: string;
}

interface AllBusinessFilterBy {
  category?: string;
}


function isNill(item) {
  return item === undefined || item === null || (item !== item);
}

function isBusiness(item, filterBy: BusinessFilterBy) {
  return (isNill(filterBy.rating) || item.rating === filterBy.rating) && (isNill(filterBy.price) || item.price === filterBy.price);
}

function isAllBusiness(item, filterBy: AllBusinessFilterBy) {
  return isNill(filterBy.category) || item.category === filterBy.category;
}

function filterBusiness(item, businessFilterBy: BusinessFilterBy) {
  return [{
    ...item,
    business: item.business.filter(businessItem => isBusiness(businessItem, businessFilterBy))
  }];
}

function transform(allBusiness = [], allBusinessFilterBy: AllBusinessFilterBy = {}, businessFilterBy: BusinessFilterBy = {}) {
  if (!allBusiness && !allBusiness.length) {
    return allBusiness;
  }
  return allBusiness.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, ...isAllBusiness(item, allBusinessFilterBy) ? filterBusiness(item, businessFilterBy) : []], []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time but something is missing and its not working. Sometimes its working when I select all 3 values (using dropdown filters). Actually it should work if I select any one of the 3 filter. Also, FYI, I have "Sort by category", "Sort by rating" & "Sort by price" as first option in the dropdown's so those should be excluded while filtering (its like resetting the filters).

Comment: Buggy - I have a created a stackblitz. Please refer to this link and help me to fix this issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utavhg

Comment: As i understood you want to `filter` rather than `sort` )
Used my answer and add to it:  
- convertNull for `Sort by <>` case . 
- filter result to ignore categories without items . 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcpd7w

Comment: Buggy - Thanks a lot... Its working now and sorry for the confusion (filter vs sort). Also, I couldn't understand what you are doing in this line...  Can you please explain? allBusiness.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, ...isAllBusiness(item, allBusinessFilterBy) ? filterBusiness(item, businessFilterBy) : []], []);

Comment: It is more clear way to say:
`allBusiness
  .filter(item => isAllBusiness(item, allBusinessFilterBy))
  .map(item => filterBusiness(item, businessFilterBy));`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure what you mean when you say *I have to show only the appropriate data*, in relation to filtering by `rating` or `price`. I assume you want to:

- Filter/exclude an item in `allBusiness` if none of the entries in its `business` array contain a specified `rating` and `price`.
- Output/include an item if it contains, at least one entry in its `business` array that has the specified `rating` and `price`.

If that is correct, you can do this:

```
return allBusiness.filter(item => 
   (selectedCategory && item.category && item.category.indexOf(selectedCategory) > -1)
   && (selectedRating && item.business && item.business.length > 0 && item.business.find(rt => rt.rating == selectedRating))
   && (selectedPrice && item.business && item.business.length > 0 && item.business.find(pr => pr.price == selectedPrice)))
```

Now, if you want to filter `allBusiness` such that you only want an entry where all items in its `business` array have the specified `rating` and `price`, you can do this:

```
return allBusiness.filter(item => 
   (selectedCategory && item.category && item.category.indexOf(selectedCategory) > -1)
   && (selectedRating && item.business && item.business.length > 0 && !item.business.find(rt => rt.rating != selectedRating))
   && (selectedPrice && item.business && item.business.length > 0 && !item.business.find(pr => pr.price != selectedPrice)))
```

**Note:**

[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) gets the first item in an array that matches the condition you give it. If no items match the condition, it returns `undefined`.

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), on the other hand, gives you a new array with only items from the original which match the condition you give it. If no items match the condition, it gives you an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Btw, "show only the appropriate data" means, if the user selects a "rating" as 4 then show only items which has rating = 4. Similarly if the user selects a "price" as "$$" then show only items price = "$$". Also, if they select both rating & price then it should show only items which satisfies both (like an AND condition). I tried both the solution you provided and nothing works. Also, FYI, I have "Sort by category", "Sort by rating" & "Sort by price" as first option in the dropdown's so those should be excluded while filtering (its like resetting the filters).